Need Help on Designing Network in Warehouse
I need help on finalizing the Network Scheme for a Warehouse.
Current System has 2 different ISP with total 6 wifi access point for 3 each since it's large Warehouse
Each ISP has 3 WiFi access points for connectivity.
In current Schenario, If a ISP goes down users has to manually connect to another WiFi.
We want to get rid of this architecture and implement single WiFi with 3 Access Points so if any ISP is down a switch changes the ISP automatically so users don't have to change the WiFi.
They are always connected to same WiFi Network.
I tried reading for SD-WAN but not sure if it's a good idea.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

You'll need a router with support for multiple WAN links (most business-grade routers do), connect it to both ISPs and then set up the fail over. We cannot recommend any products here though.

To achieve failover between two ISPs or set up load balancing, you'll need a dual WAN router or firewall. The choice depends on the number of users and whether you can invest in enterprise-grade equipment.
